# Realm using try-with-resources

Tags: android, realm

Android studio give me message that i can use try with automatic resource management.

But the docs says

> If you’re working on an app with minSdkVersion >= 19 and Java >= 7,
>   then you can use try-with-resources:

My project have `minSdkVersion 15` and `Java 1.8`.

Do i need to ignore this message or to use `try-with-resources`?

Comment: Desugaring is awesome. It makes it possible even below API 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it.

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) say the following:

> In addition to the Java 8 language features and APIs above, Android Studio 3.0 and later extends support for try-with-resources to all Android API levels.

Sidenote, please drop support for anything below api 19.